# Question about modules and their quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $L$ be an $A$-module, for a ring $A$. Let $M,N\subseteq L$ be submodules. Denote with $\bar M$ the submodule generated in $L/N$ by the image of $M$ under the projection, and analogously let $\bar N\subseteq L/M$. Are the following isomorphisms well defined? $$\frac{L/N}{\bar M}\cong\frac{L/N}{(M+N)/N}\cong\frac{L}{(M+N)}\cong\frac{L/M}{(M+N)/M}\cong\frac{L/M}{\bar N}.$$ I  would say yes, because $\bar M=(M+N)/N$, as the image of $M+N$ will contain the image of $M$, but every element of $N$ is sent to  zero (by $L\to L/N$). Analogously $\bar N\cong  (M+N)/M$, and the two central congruences hold by 2.1 on Atiyah-MacDonald.

Do  these (immediate) results really hold? I'm suspicious because I've never seen them, not even in the exercises, and in particular the first chain of congruences would seem useful. I hope it's because they are trivial and not because they are false.

Comment: This looks like just the isomorphism theorems for modules: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Modules

Comment: Let it here for the record: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4365818. Some people can still see it.